# Excel Conditional Summing

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I want to create a formula so that I can keep track of how many feet get out of a drill bit.  The data will be arranged in this way:

[image: table of individual drillings]

I want to show results of the total footage drilled by:

[image: table of drilling totals]

Any ideas on formulas?

Comment: Can you clarify for us what those numbers mean? Are they all in a single row? what is the row/column structure like?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that "Bit ID" is A1, 15685 in A2, etc...

```
=sumif(A2:A11, 15685, B2:B11)
```

Where A2:A11 specifies the various bit ids, B2:B11 specifies the numbers you want to add up, and 15682 is the specific bit id you're looking for.  That would probably actually be a reference to another cell, so you could re-use this formula for all the different bit sizes.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you are after is a pivot table:

- Enter your data as shown in your question
- Select the entire range of data
- On the insert menu, choose pivot table
- Choose somewhere to put it in the dialog which pops up
- In the field list section which appears on the right, drag the Bit ID
  into the Row Labels box at the bottom.
- Drag the Ft drilled into the Values box at the bottom
- It should default to sum, but if not, click on the ft drilled item in
  the values box, choose Value Field Settings and change the summarize
  method to Sum.